# Javascript insensitive table sorting does not work when <a href=> is around td

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sort a table when user clicks on a table header. My code works well, everything gets sorted but only when there are no `<a href=#>` around `<td>`.

`sorttable.js`

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() > y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() < y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="data_table">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Number</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/45">caregiver testing testing</a></td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/72">aaaaaaa test GoodeE</a></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/74">bbbBBBbb GoodeX</a></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/76">EEEEeFFFFgggHH GoodeC</a></td>
    <td>-7</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm JS newbie so no I'm not entirely sure what's going on with my code but I think that's the issue. How to cover such case?

Comment: I think it does work: https://jsfiddle.net/csj7ak9q/1/

Comment: I guess it's working because you've put `<a href= ...>` inside the table header which I won't do this because in a real life that shouldn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You mean it should go around the `<tr>`?

Comment: I'm not quite understand what you mean. Question updated, hope it's more understandable

Comment: I think I got it now, see my answer.

Comment: I've just had a better idea, please see my edited answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Orius nifty solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a `<td>` includes an `<a>`, and if so, replace the `<td>` with the `<a>`. Like this:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      // new code starts
      x_a = x.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      if (x_a != undefined) {
        x = x_a;
      };
      // new code ends
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      // new code starts
      y_a = y.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      if (y_a != undefined) {
        y = y_a;
      };
      // new code ends
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() > y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() < y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="data_table">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Number</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/45">caregiver testing testing</a></td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/72">aaaaaaa test GoodeE</a></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/74">bbbBBBbb GoodeX</a></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/76">EEEEeFFFFgggHH GoodeC</a></td>
    <td>-7</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Edit:

Come to think of it, it would be much simpler and safer to just replace `innerHTML` with `textContent` in the original code.

Like this:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.textContent.toUpperCase() > y.textContent.toUpperCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.textContent.toUpperCase() < y.textContent.toUpperCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="data_table">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Number</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/45">caregiver testing testing</a></td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaa test GoodeE</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/74">bbbBBBbb GoodeX</a></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/registrants/76">EEEEeFFFFgggHH GoodeC</a></td>
    <td>-7</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```